# Reachbility Issue iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, xcode7

I am using Apple Reachability class in my project. I have used this for checking network and VPN connectivity. When VPN is not connected, It gives me not reachable when I called reachabilityWithHost Method. But in iOS9, It is not working. It's showing host as reachable even when VPN is not connected. Please post solution if anyone is facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a way to check the connection using iOS9 (also compatible with iOS7-8)

```
NSURL* fullURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://reachable-in-VPN-only.com"];
BOOL isDataSourceAvailable = NO;
if ([fullURL host])
{
    NSString* hostname = [fullURL host];
    CFHostRef hostRef = CFHostCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)hostname);
    isDataSourceAvailable = CFHostStartInfoResolution(hostRef, kCFHostAddresses, nil);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy!! I found these answer to be useful